# Using a Neural Network with my own dataset

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have downloaded many face images from web. In order to learn Tensorflow I want to feed those images to a simple fully-connected neural network with a single hidden layer. I have found an example code in [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eguerzhoy/321/proj3/mnist_tf.py).

I don't know how to train, evaluate, and test the network with the downloaded images. The code owner used a '.mat' file and a .pkl file. I don't understand how he organized training and test set.

In order to run the code with my images;
Do I need to divide my images into training, test, and validation folders and turn each folder into a mat file? How am I going to provide labels for the training?

Besides, I don't understand why he used a '.pkl' file?

All in all, I would like to change this code so that I can find test, training , and validation set classification performance with my image dataset.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to use `.mat` files nor pickles. Tensorflow expects `numpy array`.

For instance, let's say you have 70000 images of size 28x28 (=784 dimensions) belonging to 10 classes. Let's also assume that you'd like to train a simple feedforward neural network to classify the images.

The **first step** would be to split the images between train and test (and validation, but let's put this aside for the sake of simplicity). For the sake of the example, let's imagine that you chose **randomly** 60000 images for your training set and 10000 for your test set.

The **second step** would be to ensure that your data has the right format. Here, you'd like your training set to consist in one numpy array of shape `(60000, 784)` for the images and another one of shape `(60000, 10)` for the labels (if you use one-hot encoding to represent your classes). As for your test set, you should have an array of shape `(10000, 784)` for the images and one of shape `(10000, 10)` for the labels.

Once you have these big numpy arrays, you should define `placeholders` that will allow you to feed data to you network during training and evaluation.

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, 10])
```

The `None` here means that you can feed a batch of any size, i.e. as many images as you want, as long as you numpy array is of shape `(anything, 784)`.

The **third step** consists in defining your model as well as the loss function and the optimizer.

The **fourth step** consists in training your network by feeding it with random batches of data using the placeholders created above. As your network is training, you can periodically print its performance like the training loss/accuracy as well as the test loss/accuracy.

You can find a complete and very simple example [here](https://github.com/benmyara/deeplearning-tensorflow/blob/master/notebooks/0_vanilla_neural_network.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BiBi. Your answer is very clear but I didn't understand one thing. How am I going to label the training images? One by one or any other way? Do you have any simple example/explanation for labeling?

Comment: Obtaining labels is one of the most tedious task. In the MNIST example, the labels were obtained manually and are now available freely for anyone to download. If you use a publicly available dataset, it most probably has labels. However, if you create you own dataset (your own images for instance), you will need to manually get the labels (assuming that you want to do supervised learning).